# React native TabNavigator navigation params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to send route params to Profile tab from button click action in Home screen. Below code is tab navigator

```
  const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  [routes.HOME]: {
    screen: FeedMainScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: tabBarLabels.HOME_TAB_LABEL,
    },
  },
  [routes.SEARCH]: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: tabBarLabels.SEARCH_TAB_LABEL,
    },
  },
  [routes.PROFILE]: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: tabBarLabels.PROFILE_TAB_LABEL,
    },
  },
```

}

and button click navigation is like this

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(routes.PROFILE, { id: this.props.user._id }, null)} />
```

and accsess param from Profile screen like this

```
constructor (props) {
 super(props)
 console.log('NavPrams', this.props.navigation.state)
}
```

alwaya undifined

Answer (score 0):

You can use connect() method to successfully map the props and use them anywhere. 
Add the below mentioned code in the class where  is written -

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: this.props.user;
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(className);
```